# How to print symbol "↑" using AfxMessageBox?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

How can I print this symbol `"↑"` using `AfxMessageBox()`?

I try to code it like this:

```
AfxMessageBox("↑");
```

After compiling, I got a strange symbol:

[image]

Does `AfxMessageBox()` not support this symbol?

Comment: Are you compiling as Unicode or MBCS?

Comment: i'm using Multi byte character set

Comment: @Jess that won’t work, you need Unicode

Comment: but my task is using only MBCS, i cannot using unicode

Comment: And put an L in front of "↑".  In Configuration Properties/General, does it really say charset MBCS?

Comment: if i put L in front of that symbol i got error C2665: 'AfxMessageBox' : none of the 2 overloads can convert parameter 1 from type 'unsigned short [4]'

Comment: @Jess that is because `AfxMessageBox()` does not support Unicode strings when `UNICODE` is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your source file is likely saved as UTF-8. To work with MBCS string literals, your source file needs to be saved in the same charset that your OS user locale is set to. Unfortunately, not many charsets  support this particular character, I think. Otherwise, you have to switch to Unicode.

If you can’t switch the whole app to Unicode, then you can at least use `MessageBoxW()` instead, eg:

```
::MessageBoxW(NULL, L"↑", L"title", MB_OK);
```

Or

```
::MessageBoxW(NULL, L"\x2191", L"title", MB_OK);
```

Comment: I highly recommend not saving the literal `↑` char into source code. Between code pages, revision control systems, and other users in different IDEs, that char will get corrupt. Instead inline `0x2191` directly into a null terminated `WCHAR` or `wchar_t` array.

Comment: If i use MessageBoxW()  i got same strange character

Comment: @selbie no need for a wchar array, you can simply escape the character as `L”\x2191”` instead. I have updated my example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it work using  L"\x2191"   thank you

Comment: I suggest you use `nullptr` instead since this is tagged with C++.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili while that is good advice in general, it makes no difference in this situation.